# Most elegant image to image frame comparison algorithm

Tags: javascript

I'm interested in finding the most elegant and 'correct' solution to this problem. I'm new to JS/PHP and I'm really excited to be working with it. The goal is to compare the size of a given image to the size of a 'frame' for the image (going to be a `<div>` or `<li>` eventually) and resize the image accordingly. Users will be uploading images of many sizes and shapes and there are going to be many sizes and shapes of frames. The goal is to make sure that any given image will be correctly resized to fit any given frame. Final implementation will be in PHP, but I'm working out the logic in JS. Here's what I have:

```
//predefined variables generated dynamically from other parts of script, these are example values showing the 'landscape in landscape' ratio issue
var $imageHeight = 150, $imageWidth = 310, $height = 240, $width = 300;         
//check image orientation
if ( $imageHeight == $imageWidth ) {
    var $imageType = 1; // square image
} else if ( $imageHeight > $imageWidth ) {
    var $imageType = 2; // portrait image
} else {
    var $imageType = 3; // landscape image
};
//check frame orientation and compare to image orientation
if ( $height == $width) { //square frame
    if ( ( $imageType === 1 ) || ( $imageType === 3 ) ) {
        $deferToHeight = true;
    } else {
        $deferToHeight = false;
    };
} else if  ( $height > $width ) { //portrait frame
    if ( ( $imageType === 1 ) || ( $imageType === 3 ) )  {
        $deferToHeight = true;
    } else {
        if (($imageHeight / $height) < 1) {
                $deferToHeight = true;
            } else {
                $deferToHeight = false;
        };
    };
} else { //landscape frame
    if ( ( $imageType === 1 ) || ( $imageType === 2 ) ) {
        $deferToHeight = false;
    } else {
        if (($imageWidth / $width) > 1) {
                $deferToHeight = true;
            } else {
                $deferToHeight = false;
        };
    };
};
//set values to match (null value scales proportionately)
if ($deferToHeight == true) { //defer image size to height of frame
    $imageWidth = null;
    $imageHeight = $height;
} else { //defer image size to width of frame
    $imageWidth = $width;
    $imageHeight = null;
};
```

I've tested it with a bunch of different values and it *works*, but I have a suspicion that I could have implemented a much more elegant solution. What could I have done better?

Comment: Belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Oh wow I didn't know this existed. Thank you, I'll post things like this over there in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I dealt with this exact problem recently, in a JS implementation:

```
// determine aspect ratios
var a1 = imageWidth / imageHeight,
    a2 = frameWidth / frameHeight,
    widthDetermined = a1 > a2;

// set scale
var scale = widthDetermined ?
    // scale determined by width
    frameWidth / imageWidth :
    // scale determined by height
    frameHeight / imageHeight;

// set size (both dimensions) based on scale
imageWidth = scale * imageWidth;
imageHeight = scale * imageHeight;
```

Much less code than your version. Note that the square case is dealt with either way, which might be true in your version as well.

Comment: Wow. This is really great. Can you explain the `box` and `startbox` parameters, please? I think I grasp everything but that part. Thank you so much for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, that was a cut and paste fail. This was just referring to the image and frame - see my edit above.

Comment: No problem! I ran it and it works really well. How would you account for cases in which the ratio of the image width to the frame width is greater than that of the image height to the frame height? For example, in the supplied values we end up with an image that fills the frame horizontally, but not vertically. In those cases, we must defer to the height. If I'm reading your version correctly, we'll end up deferring to the width.

Comment: Are we aiming at the same outcome here? In my version, an image that fills the frame horizontally but not vertically *should* have the scale determined by width, with empty space at the top and bottom. Are you thinking of something else?

Comment: No. My apologies. I should have been more explicit. If there would be empty space at the top and bottom as you describe (or left and right for a portrait), the image should scale up and become partially cropped.

Comment: In that case, all you have to do is reverse the `>` to `<` in `widthDetermined = a1 > a2`. That way the smaller dimension will be used to determine the scale.

Answer (score 0):

if the image is suppose a square image and you want to convert it into portrait, dont you think the image would look as if it was elongated? i feel the proportion would be changed and the image might look bad. what do u think about the same?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that in cases like that the image will be clipped. The images will never be disproportionately stretched.